# Use Video without <video> tag

Tags: video, gif

I have a complicated situation. 
I am trying to autoplay a video on the homepage of a website hosted by my university. They do not allow us to use the video tag because of server constraints. The video also cannot be posted to youtube or vimeo without breaching terms of the license from Adobe Stock. I converted the video to a .gif, but load times are terrible. 
Is there any work around?

Css

```
 .banner {
background: url("https://labs.visual.ucla.edu/sallam/files/view/AdobeStock_123017893.gif");
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 50vh;}

.title {
position: absolute;
top: 55%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white
}
```

Html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="banner">
<div class="title">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">
    Looking Inside an Enemy&#39;s Playbook
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, please provide some pieces of the code and also anything that you already tried. Also please clarify what you mean by `they do not allow us to use tags`, how can you modify the website without writing any `html`?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the restriction is on hosting videos on the server, not on using the html5 video tag in a website.

Videos can use a lot of space and streaming them effectively usually requires specialist streaming servers if you want to do it correctly.

Your idea of hosting the video on a separate site and just embedding a link to it on your site makes sense, although the embedded code will likely make use of the video tag if that really is a restriction.

Vimeo and other services generally offer a paid solution for videos you want to keep private and restrict access to and often will provide DRM protection also - you may find that this allows you to meet the terms required by your content owner.

Comment: The video tag is prevented before I can even save any edits to the website. Even if I pay for private service with Vimeo, it still is copy right infringement with the license that I got from adobe stock. And I had been able to use an iframe before I realized the restrictions to the license.

Comment: @Alia - ok, that is an odd restriction. An iFrame like: <iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"> actually has a video tag inside it anyway. You could write your own separate website hosting the video and having the video tag there, and include the link in an iframe in a similar way to YouTube but it means you need to host the site someplace and it seems a lot of work to get around the restriction, so probably worth checking it will be allowed (or being confident it will not be detected...) first.